# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation with a change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $T: R^{2}_{E} \rightarrow R^{2}_{B}$ is a linear transformation where

$$
T(x_{1}e_{1} + x_{2}e_{2}) = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_{1} + 3x_{2} \\\ 4x_{1} - 5x_{2} \end{bmatrix}
$$

E = standard basis of R^{2}

$B = \{ b_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr 2 \end{bmatrix}, b_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \cr 5 \end{bmatrix} \} $

Is the matrix representation of $T$ just the following matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\\ 4 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $x_1=1, x_2=0,$ we find:

$$T(e_1)=T(1\cdot e_1 + 0\cdot e_2)=\begin{bmatrix} 2\cdot 1+3\cdot 0 \cr 4\cdot 1-5\cdot 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \cr 4 \end{bmatrix}=2b_1+0b_2,$$
similarly:

$$T(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \cr -5 \end{bmatrix}=25b_1-11b_2.$$

Thus the matrix representation of $T$ is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 25\cr 0& -11\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm still not understanding how any of that works. Would you be able to add en edit explaining how T(e1) and T(e2) equal what the do?

Comment: I have hopefully made the process slightly more clear. The last section of the response follows from how we define matrices for a given linear transformation.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you very much!